# chrome pointer-events not working on hover

Tags: javascript

I am implementing simple drag drop. When ghost element hovers any background element the background should change. It i working fine on Firefox and IE but not on chrome:

Code:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>

    <div class="ghost"></div>
 </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var dragOn = false;
$('.ghost').hide();
$('.element').on("mousedown", function(e) {
   dragOn = true;
});
$('.container').on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if(dragOn) {
        $('.ghost')[0].style.top = e.clientY - 30 + 'px';
        $('.ghost')[0].style.left = e.clientX - 20 + 'px';
        $('.ghost').show();
    }

});
$('.container').on("mouseup", function(e) {
    dragOn = false;
    $('.ghost').hide();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    height : 340px;
    width:330px;
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: default;

}

.element {
    height : 40px;
    width:30px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float :left;
    margin:4px;
}

.element:hover {

    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color:blue;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.ghost {
    height : 40px;
    width:30px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color:yellow;
    opacity: 0.7; 
    pointer-events: none;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Following is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tzye712k/2/

Comment: It seems on chrome, it only works for the box that you originally clicked on for dragging

Comment: Look at my answer, simple fix for this

Comment: @ChrisBeckett what are you talking about, your change makes no difference. OP wants the background colour to change on the boxes when dragging the yellow box over the rest of the box. It's in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a bug in chrome, but you can implement a workaround using jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/tzye712k/3/

```
$( ".element" ).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    // define a css class and addClass here if you want
    $(this).css('background-color','blue');
  }, mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','transparent');
  }
});
```

Chain them together if you want

```
$(".element").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
    },
    mousedown: function () {
        dragOn = true;
    }
});
```